# How can I half the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am learning to code and I am trying out this javascript object method course. I am currently stuck on this method. I want to have the array with three different numbers(10,20,5) to be /2. I do not understand why it is returning NaN. Thank you for reading.

```
shirtPrice = 10
jeanPrice = 20
shoePrice = 5

shoppingList = [shirtPrice,jeanPrice,shoePrice];

const shoppingDiscountDay = {
  discountedItems: {
    calculateItemsDiscount() {
        return shoppingList/2; //return NaN
    },
  }
}
console.log(shoppingDiscountDay.discountedItems.calculateItemsDiscount());
```

Comment: You’ll need [`shoppingList.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this one. (Your code indentation looks good, but the way.)

Comment: Do you want the numbers to be totaled, and then divided by two, or do you want each number in the array to simply be divided by two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .map()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const shoppingDiscountDay = {
  discountedItems: {
    calculateItemsDiscount() {
        const itemsHalfPrice = shoppingList.map(item=>item/2)
        return itemsHalfPrice;

    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot divide an array, you need to divide each of the elements in it.

You can use the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which applies a function on each of the elements of an array and returns a new array with the results

```js
shirtPrice = 10
jeanPrice = 20
shoePrice = 5

shoppingList = [shirtPrice, jeanPrice, shoePrice];

const shoppingDiscountDay = {
  discountedItems: {
    calculateItemsDiscount() {
      return shoppingList.map(itemPrice => itemPrice / 2);
    },
  }
}
console.log(shoppingDiscountDay.discountedItems.calculateItemsDiscount());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform '/' operation on array. It is meant to be perform on numbers. Instead try this.

```
shirtPrice = 10
jeanPrice = 20
shoePrice = 5

shoppingList = [shirtPrice,jeanPrice,shoePrice];

const shoppingDiscountDay = {
  discountedItems: {
    calculateItemsDiscount() {
       for(let i = 0;  i < shoppingList.length; i++){
          shoppingList[i] = shoppingList[i]/2;  
       }
        return shoppingList; 
    },
  }
}
console.log(shoppingDiscountDay.discountedItems.calculateItemsDiscount());
```

Comment: careful though, this will modify the original array